# VHDL 3 digit 7 segment display

Tags: vhdl, cyclone

I have a problem with code snippet from http://langster1980.blogspot.com/2015/09/more-on-seven-segment-displays-and.html

My code:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity main is
port ( 
    clock_in : in std_logic;
    Seven_Segment_Enable : out std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
    Seven_Segment_Display : out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0) 
         );
end main;

architecture Behavioral of main is

signal refresh_count : integer := 0;
signal refresh_clk : std_logic := '1';

signal second_count : integer := 0;
signal second_clk : std_logic := '1';

signal digit_sel : unsigned(1 downto 0);
signal bcd : integer := 0;
signal Seven_Segment_Display_output : std_logic_vector (7 downto 0) := (others => '0');
signal bcd0, bcd1, bcd2 : integer := 0;

signal unit_count : integer := 0;
signal ten_count : integer := 0;
signal hundred_count : integer := 0;

begin

process(Clock_in)

begin

if(clock_in'event and clock_in='1') then 
refresh_count <= refresh_count+1;
second_count <= second_count+1;

if(second_count = 750000) then
second_clk <= not second_clk;
second_count <= 1;
end if;

if(refresh_count = 1200) then
refresh_clk <= not refresh_clk;
refresh_count <= 1;
end if;

end if;

end process; 

process(second_clk)

begin

if(second_clk'event and second_clk='1') then
  bcd0 <= 0;
  bcd1 <= 1;
  bcd2 <= 2;

end if;

end process;

process(refresh_clk)

begin

if(refresh_clk' event and refresh_clk='1') then
digit_sel <= digit_sel + 1;

end if;  

end process;

with digit_sel select
    bcd <= bcd0 when "00",
           bcd1 when "01",
           bcd2 when others;

with digit_sel select
    Seven_Segment_Enable <= "110" when "00",
                            "101" when "01",
                            "011" when others;
with bcd select

Seven_Segment_Display_output(7 downto 0) <= B"00000011" when 0,
     B"11110011" when 1,
     B"00100101" when 2,
     B"01100001" when 3,
     B"11010001" when 4,
     B"01001001" when 5,
     B"00001001" when 6,
     B"11100011" when 7,
     B"00000001" when 8,
     B"01000001" when 9,
     B"11111111" when others;

Seven_Segment_Display(7 downto 0) <= Seven_Segment_Display_output(7 downto 0);  

end Behavioral;
```

My problem is with draw on display.
According to code should be draw number 012, but me result is
[image: this]
(Click to enlarge)

and I don't know how to fix it.
Don't you know what to do?

Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Ahh! The famous 3 segment VHDL code school assignment we see over and over. Please provide you test-bench as well. By the way, at a glance I count at least have three clocks. **Don't**! Always run everything from one clock.

Comment: I don't believe your `clock_in` has a frequency of 1.5 MHz. `digit_sel` has 4 states, but the two multiplexer using it have 3 inputs. The 3rd state is active twice. This circuit description is not synchronous. Non of the `7 downto 0` slices is required.

Comment: I added a comment at the source and asked for improvements, because the snippet you found is one of the worst I saw so far on the Internet.